# How to stop application windows from shifting to workspace one after attaching dual monitor?

Tags: ubuntu, xrandr, multi-monitor, workspaces, unity

I'm using Unity on Ubuntu 13.04.

I use `arandr` to configure my dual monitor setup. The problem is as soon as I apply my settings, the display resets and all application windows, which I had tediously arranged along my four workspaces shift to workspace one.

How can I make the windows stay where they are?

Comment: What window manager or desktop environment do you use?

Comment: os is ubuntu 13.04

Comment: default window manager is unity ...